# Can Cloud Firestore easily give the total amount in a collections?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, count, google-cloud-firestore

When using the good old Firebase Realtime Database and wanting to get a count of a node, total numbers, let´s say the node contains chat messages. As I understood this, this was possible using Android Firebase Realtime Database but the downside was that i must download the entire node tree all chat messages and count them locally.

What about new beta Cloud Firestore, is there an easier way to do what I describe above?